# Show $L$ is not a stopping time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $L = \sup\{ n : n \le 10; A_n \in B \}$, $B \in \mathcal B$,  $\sup\{\emptyset \}=0$. $(A_n)_{n \ge1}$ is a process adapted by a natural filtration $\{\mathcal F_n\}.$ Show that $L$ is NOT a stopping time (unless A is 'freaky').

Comment: If $L$ is a stopping time, you know at time $k$ whether $L=k$.  Suppose you observe $A_1, A_2, A_3$ and it happens that $A_3 \in B$.  So at time $3$, do you know whether $L=3$?  That is, do you know at time $3$ whether $A_n$ comes back to $B$ at some time $4 \le n \le 10$?

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, your interpretation is really good, and I have noticed this problem, I just dont know how to write the proof.

Comment: I think you probably need some additional conditions on $B$ here. If for example $B = \emptyset$ (or if the probability space satisfies the usual conditions then any $\mathbb{P}$-null set), then $L$ would be a stopping time.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did miss something I think is not so important, which is $B \in \mathcal B$, and in a book it said L is not a stopping time unless $A$ is freaky. Thats all the information it provided. And I am not so sure what 'freaky' means here.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments I think you need some more conditions on $B$ for your statement to be completely true. I'm not sure what the weakest conditions on $B$ can be.

If L is a stopping time then $\{L \le 9\} \in \mathcal{F}_9$, this in turn indicates that $\{A_{10} \in B^c\} \in \mathcal{F}_{9}$. In general this could be a contradiction, but for some specific $B$ it is not.

Or perhaps to make my criticism more concrete suppose that $A_n$ is your fortune at the $n$th step of a game where you toss a coin every round and double your money on heads and lose it all on tails. Also suppose you start with $A_0 = 1$. If $B$ were the set $(-\infty, 2^{10})$ then above you get a contradiction; but if it is the set $(-\infty, 2^{10} + 1)$ then no matter what $A_{10} \in B$. Even at time $n=0$ you will know this, so in fact $\{A_{10} \in B^c\} \in \mathcal{F}_{n}$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Comment: correct observation

Comment: 'If L is a stopping time' is precisely for what I was looking (a rigorous approach). Brilliant! Hadn't thought of using proof by contradiction. Thanks!

Comment: Kai Sikorski, is $\{A_n < 2^{10}\}$ really an element of $\mathscr{B}$ and not $\mathscr{F}$ ? I think it's supposed to be $(-\infty, 2^{10})$